# Create mobile application (iOS, Android, WP)

Tags: php, web-services, mobile

If got a task to create a mobile application for iOS, Android and WP. This application needs to access a mySQL database which is already in use by the website running php.

What I found in the meantime, is that I have to create a php webservice and use this webservice to access the data in the mySQL database.

Since I did not found any clear advice which way is the best to do it (JSON, XML, REST, etc) - I just wanted to ask you, is there a kind of best practice which technologies should be used for the php webservice?

Additional it would be great for me if someone knows a good tutorial for the recommended technology.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am arriving a bit late but here is my answer : I believe that the easier way currently available is a PhoneGap application (with Sencha Touch or jQuery Mobile as a javascript framework) talking to the server through a simple PHP webservice. PhoneGap allows you to build an Android, iOS and WP app with the same codebase.

We use that technology in my company and it works great.